# Creating an OpenLayers map in Node.js View

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, openlayers-3

I'm new to node.js and am attempting to put a simple OpenLayers map on a page.  However, the map is not showing up.

## Code:

> app.js

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {title: 'Map Viewer'}); 
}); 

app.get('/map', function(req, res){
    res.render('view'); 
}); 

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000...'); 
});
```

> layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
    head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  
    body
        block content
```

> view.jade

```
extends layout 
block content 
    #map 


script(type='text/javascript').

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'Global Imagery',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
          params: {LAYERS: 'nasa:bluemarble', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
        })
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 0,
      maxResolution: 0.703125
    })
  });
```

In `package.json` I'm using `"openlayers": "^3.15.1"`

## Result:

The above code is producing a blank page with the following html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"> 
    <body>
        <div id="map"> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that in `view.jade` the Javascript block is not indented over. Everything under and including `script(type='text/javascript').` needs to be indented one space.

The other issue is that `ol.js` isn't being imported.  In `layout.jade` the following line must be added:

```
script(type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.15.1/ol.js")
```